# Menu items disappear

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, menuitem

When I edit the content of a node/panel in Drupal 7, the menu item linking to that page disappears from the menu.

Is there any solution for this? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the automatic alias feature may be re-writing your urls. I'm not 100% sure this is it, but something to look at if you haven't already.

When editing a node, click on the URL path settings and make sure the automatic alias is unchecked if you want to retain an alias that is not standard to the default path patterns.

Comment: No I don't have the automatic alias checked on any of the pages, but I have aliases set for each page in the menu.

Comment: Try setting the exact node path for the menu item destination (node/123), instead of the alias itself. It will render as the alias. Just tossing out things I'd try as I learn and decipher bugs from actual changes in D7 myself.